# Force margin to use all width

Tags: html, css, list

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Ms6/1/)

I need these boxes in example to be placed the same size out of each other on the same line. How it could be possible to make? 
Also, if you resize window and one box drops down, then it would be in the center like it is now in the start of the example.

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:
[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest using `div`s instead of `<ul>` and `<li>` otherwise you will have to reset styles on them (for example, chrome adds `-webkit-margin-before/after` and other css properties that can mess up your layout).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/k4Ms6/15/) with `divs`.

If you really need to keep you HTML markup, here is a

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/k4Ms6/16/)** taht works in chrome.

HTML :

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <ul>
        <li><span></span>
        </li>
        <li><span></span>
        </li>
        <li><span></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #000;
}
ul {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start:0;
}
ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:33.33%;
    height: 220px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul > li > span {
    background-color: red;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it's just a little bit more. In your example I need additionally add same margins between two boxes. Is it clear, or may be I should pin an image to make it more clearer?

Comment: @eatmypants an image would be great

Comment: @eatmypants in your first comment, you say you can "pin an image to make it clearer" I'm taliking about that image.

Comment: @eatmypants I think so! updated my answer (see about `div`) and here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/k4Ms6/16/